# Android - How to call method in custom View from Main Activity?

Tags: java, android

I have created a custom View that will display a circle (the idea is that the user will be able to interact with this "ball" in various ways)
From my main activity class, I want to adjust some of the "ball's" properties, in this case change its color.

My problem is that nothing happens (no errors either, the app runs but doesn't do what I want) when I try to call the various methods from my MainActivity class, but if I do it from CircleView class, it works (for example changing the color upon touch)

Here is my custom View class (CircleView.java):

```
public class CircleView extends View {
    private int circleColor = Color.GREEN;
    private Paint paint;

    public CircleView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init(context, null);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_SCROLL:
                this.circleColor = setRandomColor();
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                this.circleColor = setRandomColor();
                invalidate();
                break;

        }
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    public CircleView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init(context, attrs);
    }

    private void init(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    public void setCircleColor(int circleColor) {
        this.circleColor = circleColor;
        invalidate();
    }

    public int setRandomColor() {
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomColor = Color.argb(255, random.nextInt(), random.nextInt(), random.nextInt());
        return randomColor;
    }

    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
//...
//someXvalue, someYvalue, someRadius are being set here
//...

        paint.setColor(circleColor);
        canvas.drawCircle(someXvalue, someYvalue, someRadius, paint);
    }
}
```

And here is my MainActivity.java class:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        GestureDetector.OnGestureListener {

    private GestureDetectorCompat mDetector;      
    CircleView circle;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
        circle = new CircleView(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        this.mDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent event) {
        return true;
    }  

    @Override
    public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
        circle.setCircleColor(circle.setRandomColor(0));
        circle.invalidate();
        return true;
    }
}
```

I am new to Android development, and Java as well. I realize it could be something with the Context, which is something I have not fully understood yet. Could also be something with the TouchEvents. I am sure that someone out there can see my mistake. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

your `circle` view is not a part of activity's layout , it's just a object in memory which has no link to your activity screen so solutions

1.) Either set `circle` as Activity's view

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDetector = new GestureDetectorCompat(this, this);
        circle = new CircleView(this);
        setContentView(circle);
    }
```

2.) you can create your `<yourpackagename.CircleView ...attributes .../>` tag in your `activity_main.xml` and then use `findViewById` to initialize it in your activity.

Comment: Ah, that was the problem! I just changed "
        circle = new CircleView(this);" to "
        circle = (CircleView)findViewById(R.id.circleView);" and now it works. Thank you for seeing this.

Comment: @Zerato i am glad that we (i and Mr.Gabe) could help , happy coding

Answer (score 3):

1)If all you want to do with gestures is on tap, just implement an onClickListener on your View instead.

2)You aren't actually using the GestureDetector anywhere.  The way it works is you set an onTouchListener for the view you want to get gestures on, and send the events to the gesture detector.  You aren't ever sending data for any view to the detector, so it will never do anything.

3)Not a bug just an oddness-  why circle.setColor(circle.setRandomColor())?  I would expect a function named setXXX to actually set XXX, rather than having to do it yourself later.  Not following that convention will work, but make debugging and maintenance hard.

Edit:  Also what @Pavneet_Singh said-  your circle isn't in your layout anywhere, so it won't be on screen.

Comment: The code I posted is just a part of my program, the part I thought necessary to illustrate my problem. In reality, I am using all sorts of gestures to rezise, move and throw the ball. I'm not sure exactly what you mean in 2) but the goal is to have a gesture detector only in MainActivity. You are right about 3), it would be better to name that method just "randomColor()" or something, or to actually do the Invalidate() inside the method.